# OutOfMemory error when executing rules for decision table using statelessKieSession

Tags: java, out-of-memory, drools

I am executing rules for a decision table using statelessKieSession.

I have 1000 objects and 10 rules for each object so total I have 10000 rules for one row. Rules will process for each row in the decision table. Currently before finishing the execution of one row I am getting OutOfMemory error.

Any idea about this issue?

From the below link you can refer the memory usage details and find the classes which creates more instances while executing the rules.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code snippet if possible.

Comment: What is the message in `OutOfMemoryError`? Is it heap space problem or something else?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Some times i am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded and some times i am getting  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Are you creating new objects as part of the conditions or actions? It might help to see the rules if possible, as I reckon somehow the rules are creating combinations or something similar of pairs/groups of those 1000 objects.

Comment: What version of Drools?